# Update nested array using setState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to setState() to edit  **parameter** value which is in **parameterData** *Array*.
using setState method. **If we can do this *without* any third part library like  [Immutabilty helper](https://reactjs.org/docs/update.html) or [lodash](https://lodash.com/) that would be great!**

#### The Given state is

```
   const[state,setState]= useState ([{
    "id": 0,
    "targets": {
        "ageGender": {
        "key":value
        },
        "parameterData": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "parameter": "Low",
                "expression": "<",
                "val": "10",
                "indicator": "Select"
            },
            
        ]
    }
}])
```

I have tried this solution
where

> idx = state index where object is situated 
>   index = index of
> parameterData array to be changed 
>   event = event of change

```
  const handleChangeTextParameter = (event, index, idx) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;

    setState((prev) => {
      const newState = prev.map((obj, index1) => {
        let fil;
        if (index1 === idx) {
          fil = obj.targets.parameterData.map((data, indexOne) => {
            if (indexOne === index) {
              return { ...data, parameter: value };
            }
            return data;
          });
          const p = obj.targets.parameterData.map(
            (obj) => fil.find((o) => o.id === obj.id) || obj
          );

          return { ...obj, targets: { ...obj.targets, parameterData: p } };
        }
      });

      return newState;
    });

    
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer:* The state variables you defined are called `state` and `setState`, but in your `handleChangeTextParameter` you are using `setTargets` so I assume they are the same
I think the following should work:

```js
setTargets((prev) => {
    const newTargets = prev.map((object, objectIndex) => {
        if (objectIndex !== idx) return object;
        return {
            ...object,
            targets: {
                ...object.targets,
                parameterData: object.target.parameterData.map((data, dataIndex) => {
                    if (dataIndex !== index) return data;
                    return { ...data, parameter: value };
                }),
            },
        };
    });
    return newTargets;
});
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to edit the setState

Comment: const cpyTarget = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(targets));
    cpyTarget[idx].targets.parameterData[index]["val"] = value;
    setTargets(cpyTarget); I tried  this and it worked

Comment: Yeah, this way of `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))`copying is probably the best unless you want to flex with nested `.map` etc :) Glad it worked! :)

Comment: yes thanks! But still we should avoid nested array state . its a mess!